# Django Rest Framework get a parameter from the URL, ignore the one in body

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django 1.9 and Django Rest Framework 3.3. I have incoming POST requests that can either be a `dict` or a `list`, hitting the same API endpoint. The endpoint URL looks like this: `/api/children/3/classes`. This `3` denotes the ID of the child.

My incoming POST request looks like this:

```
{
   "name": "Mathematics",
   "teacher": "Mr. Kabbatt",
   "school": "High School"
   "child": 2
}
```

In this case I've given a dict, but it can also be an array (list) of dicts as well.

How can I force Django Rest Framework to **ignore** the `child` parameter that is set in the POST body and **only** use the one from the URL? I am using the `ListCreateAPIView` generic and I have been able to obtain the `child` parameter in the `get_queryset()` method. On the serializer side, I am using a simple `ModelSerializer` from DRF with all fields included.

Comment: Can you add your view code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to override the `child` value on the request body using the parameter provided by the url.

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # django passes params from url in kwargs
    # e.g. {id: 3} or {child: 3}, not sure what your url calls it
    if request.data.__class__ is dict:
        request.data['child'] = kwargs['id']
    elif request.data.__class__ is list:
        # dunno what your setup looks like here
        for i in request.data:
            request.data[i]['child'] = kwargs['id']
    self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```